# How to use updateOne in Mongodb using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, javascript-objects

Below is my code to update a website field in Mongodb using NodeJS, instead of updating however it adds a new field to my database.

```
let { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

  async get(id) {
    if (!id) throw 'You must provide an id to search for';

    const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
    const res = await restaurantsCollection.findOne({ _id: id });
    if (res === null) throw 'No dog with that id';
    res._id = res._id.toString().replace(/ObjectId\("(.*)"\)/, "$1")
    return res;
  }

async rename(id, newWebsite) {
    if (!id) throw 'You must provide an id to search for';

    if (!newWebsite) throw 'You must provide a name for the restaurant';

    let newid = ObjectId(id);
  
    const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
    const updatedInfo = await restaurantsCollection.updateOne(
      { _id: newid },
      { $set: {website:newWebsite} }
    );
    if (updatedInfo.modifiedCount === 0) {
      throw 'could not update restaurant successfully';
    } 
    
    return await this.get(newid);
  } 
};
```

Below is the output I get:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6157825a4dcae5beb8f759bf"),
  name: 'Hey',
  location: 'New York City, New York',
  phoneNumber: '123-456-7890',
  website: 'http://www.hey.com',
  priceRange: '$$$$',
  cuisines: [ 'Cuban', 'Italian' ],
  overallRating: 3,
  serviceOptions: { dineIn: true, takeOut: true, delivery: false },
  newWebsite: 'http://www.hi.com'
}
```

Instead of the website being replaced from hey.com to hi.com it just adds a new field, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mongo isn't adding a field called "newWebsite", you are. But not in the code you've shown. Since the key is the same as your variable name, it's an object-shorthand syntax mistake somewhere.

Comment: Try logging the ```newWebsite``` and check the value, type. 
Also set some hardcoded value and test. Ex : ```{ $set: {website:"some hardcoded value"} }```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `{ $set: {website:newWebsite} }`

It should just be `{website:newWebsite}`

Comment: I tried it, does not work.